# Simple Mux Equation finding, need help?

Tags: circuit-analysis, multiplexer, computer-architecture, logic-gates

How we can find the equation of following simple diagram ?

[image]

My TA solved it as :  `C.Not(B).A + B.Not(A)`

Comment: You can start by writing the truth table i.e by writing the output for each and every possible combination of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to start is to make a truth table.  For each of the 4 possible combinations of A and B, show what comes out.  Note that the output can be either 0, 1, or C.